# Vanity over an air register

Tags: tile, vent, vanity, air, register

Our existing vanity had a deep kick plate to allow for the air register, now we have a new floor laid and I've even shortened toe register from 12 inches to 10 inches but almost any vanity I can find (needs to be about a 30 inch wide vanity) seems like it will sit on the floor register. I'll include a couple pictures. Really frustrating. What would you do?

https://imgur.com/a/bDOclAt

Comment: Make sure the kick plate is attached with screws if the register needs to be replace.  Can shave/cut the bottom of kick plate to fit the register.  It looks like you only lose a tiny bit of the register area.

Comment: Seems to me the thing to do here would've been to shorten the register even more...